# Django admin change list hide checkbox

Tags: django

Is it possible to hide some checkboxes in the admin change list, thee are the default ones that get added.  I would rather not extend it.  I am after something like this

```
if obj.name == 'read only':
    #hide the checkbox of that row
```

Added an example of the boxes I want to change

[image]

Thanks

Grant

Comment: Share your model and admin definition for the particular model you want to change.

Comment: what checkboxes? for a boolean field on your model?

Comment: Just added an example of what I want to change, these are the checkboxes that get added by default

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.  In my admin I linked to a js file with my function

```
class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = (
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', # jquery
            'js/admin-help.js',       # project static folder
        )
```

Then, in my js file I loop through the table looking for a value called 'read only' in a cell.  With that I then set the action-select checkbox to disabled.

```
function read_only_checkboxes(){
     $("#result_list").find("tr").each(function() { //get all rows in table
        getType = $(this).find('td.field-api_type').text();
        if (getType == 'read only'){
            $(this).find('input.action-select').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
}
```

This works, and gives me the desired affect

Thanks

Grant